# Native phoneGap database

Tags: android, cordova

Maybe someone knows, if phoneGap has a native database which could be use for Android/iOS?

I'm trying to choose which way is the best to write a data-driven app, in PhoneGap or native Android?

Comment: html5 has native database access on android and iOS, independent of phonegap.  If your needs are simple.

Comment: I need smth like SQLite database in android native applications, because my app will be synchronizing with local ERP.